# Display multiple page contents under single page

Tags: pages

Is it possible to display the content of all the pages under a single page??
Like, I have Home, About and Contact us pages. I want all of its contents to display under a single frontend page. Is it possible and how can we do it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @manish-shresth Yes, this is possible with this plugin [link] (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-single-page/) also there are some templates with this effect

Answer (score 1):

This is really pretty trivial to implement. [A few minutes with the Codex should solve the problem, really.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ($q->have_posts()) {
  while ($q->have_posts()) {
    $q->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
  }
}
```

Any additional markup and formatting (CSS), of course, is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the following code under index.php for each post, where PAGE_ID_GOES_HERE is the ID number of the post.

```
<?php 
 $id=PAGE_ID_GOES_HERE; 
 $post = get_post($id); 
 $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
 echo $content;  
 ?>
```

To find the ID number of the page, look at the URL of the post-edit page; for example, in http://yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=8&action=edit post=8 tells you that the ID number is 8.